# Set jquery cookie for one year

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookies

I am trying to create a cookie for 365 days on a form submission using jquery cookie library.

It is working as expected on chrome and other browsers but on safari, the expiry date is set for 7 days even though I have set it for 365 days.

Any idea why is it not working as expected on Safari?

**Chrome and other browsers** - 2022-10-06 *(For a year as expected)*

**Safari** - 13/10/2021 *(for a week which is wrong)*

Here is the code

```
$.cookie("login", "logedin", { path: "/shop", expires: 365 });
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea why is it not working as expected on Safari?

Because Apple has decided to introduce this limit as part of their Intelligent Tracking Protection.

You can read more about it f.e. here, https://webkit.org/blog/8613/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-1/,

> **Client-Side Cookies Capped to 7 Days of Storage**.
> Cookies can either be set in HTTP responses or through the document.cookie API, the latter sometimes referred to as client-side cookies. With ITP 2.1, all persistent client-side cookies, i.e. persistent cookies created through document.cookie, are capped to a seven day expiry.

Or https://clearcode.cc/blog/intelligent-tracking-prevention-faq/,

> First-party cookies created by JavaScript’s document.cookie will expire in 7 days. If the cookies are accessed within those 7 days, then their expiration date will be extended by 7 days.

Comment: so there is no way of extending the duration?

Comment: This is a measure to try and stop bad people from doing bad things (user tracking, privacy invasion.) It would be a pretty _pointless_ measure, if it could be easily circumvented. // As the second link I quoted says, the cookie expiration will automatically be extended by a further seven days, if it gets accessed within those first seven days.